# if checkbox checked that time first select option selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

if checkbox `checked` that time first select option `selected` but below code works first time. when second time checked it will not working.

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="ivrs02_yes">
<select class="destination_type_select3">
    <option>slect</option>    
    <option>slect2</option>
    <option>slect3</option>
</select>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".ivrs02_yes").click( function(){
        $('.destination_type_select3 option:first-child').attr("selected", "selected");
    });
});
```

Comment: not getting what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way..

```
$(".ivrs02_yes").change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
       $('.destination_type_select3 option:eq(0)').prop('selected', true);
    }
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".ivrs02_yes").change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('.destination_type_select3 option:eq(0)').prop('selected', true);
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="ivrs02_yes">
<select class="destination_type_select3">
  <option>slect</option>
  <option>slect2</option>
  <option>slect3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".ivrs02_yes").click( function(){

```
    if($(".ivrs02_yes").prop('checked') == true)
    {
        $("select").find("option:first").attr("selected", true);
    }
    else
    {
        $("select").find("option:first").removeAttr("selected",true)
    }

    });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this its working fine,

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){


    $(".ivrs02_yes").click( function(){

var b=$(".ivrs02_yes").prop('checked');
if(b){ 

$(".destination_type_select3").prop('selectedIndex',1);
}
    });
});
</script>
```

Thanks,
Amit Kumar